# Connect to VNC from Windows

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to a mac screen sharing from a windows machine using tightvnc

I'm getting the error

"Server did not offer supported security type"

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Vine Server VNC as the server on the mac and open up port 5900, and VNC Viewer on the PC (or any other vnc viewer) you'll be fine.  Its not native, but its more flexible.

This, of course, is a free solution.

See this thread on mac screen sharing:

- [Controlling a Mac remotely](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/controlling-a-mac-remotely/6357#6357)

Vine Server here:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/

UltraVNC (client viewer only):

- http://www.uvnc.com/download/1082/1082viewer.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is shared here  - http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=380251 (its someways in the middle of the thread). Do give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this error too, from all the free VNC clients I've tried on Windows.  None of them are able to authenticate the way the Mac wants; you will probably have to buy the more advanced version for it to work.  TightVNC doesn't appear to be offered for money (just one free version), but RealVNC does and will probably work.

You could also figure out how to configure the security on the Mac so the free Windows client will work, but that's a.) probably a very techie thing to do and b.) dangerous because you're exposing your machine to control for anybody with network access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that;

in System Preferences, Sharing, Screen Sharing, Computer Settings:
you have "VNC viewers may control screen with password:" checked.  And a password filled in.