# Free or Cheaper Alternatives to Apple Remote Desktop 3

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop

Apple Remote Desktop isn't a bad program. It's a bit overdue for an update, has some issues, but is an otherwise solid program. The big downside to ARD is the price, however.

I'm trying to find an option for teachers in primary/elementary classrooms to have all the computers in their class up on the projector (which you can do with remote desktop) but I don't want to pay the US$499 unlimited seat option (education pricing is a bit cheaper, but still too much). I'm aware you can VNC using the Finder in Snowleopard, but I'm hoping for a tidy program that can simultaneously show (view) several macs. VNC *Control* would be nice, but isn't necessary. Ideally (almost essential) it will use the existing screen sharing engine in Sharing.preferences.

**Update**
It's important that the product can show more than one screen at the same time. Logmein free is a great product but doesn't do this.

Comment: You can get Apple Remote Desktop on the Mac App Store [for $80](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375?mt=12)

Comment: No way! I had no idea. I have a version on my lappy so it doesn't show the price, just 'installed'. Question still stands, it would nice if there were free alternatives to roll out to our staff; but that's really good to know.

Comment: You can try a program called TeamViewer. You can read the description and download for free here, 
http://download.cnet.com/TeamViewer/3000-7240_4-10869706.html?tag=mncol;pop

Comment: You can check this other question where ARD is named but also other alternatives: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6133/1227

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARD is now available on the Mac App Store for only [$79.99](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375?mt=12).

ARD aside, you can do pretty much anything ARD can do with Screen Sharing, File Sharing, scp, ssh and AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

LogMeIn has a [free Mac/PC remote login/access service](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/free/). Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

[RHUB](http://www.rhubcom.com) remote support appliances provide the option of showing more than one screen at the same time. Try it out.